# How do I add permissions for a LinkedIn app on the developer portal (e.g. r_liteprofile, r_emailaddress, etc.)?

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

In the developer's portal for a LinkedIn app I am designing, I am not seeing a "permissions" section under the "Auth" tab. At this point, all I need is access to the r_liteprofile permissions in order to access the "Sign in with LinkedIn" product. On the [products page](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/products)
the "Sign in" product is classified at the top as a consumer product, which, according to the page, "can be instantly added to your app".

Meanwhile, on my app's developer's portal under the "Products" tab, the "Sign in with LinkedIn" product is listed, but when selected, it says that my app needs to be reviewed, and that access to the "Sign In" feature (and presumably the r_liteprofile permissions, too) will only be granted once it is approved (i.e. *not instantly*). My main concern is that my app is in the early stages of development, and I'm afraid that I won't get approved. Is there a way around this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so that there is any other way. In V2 API Approval process is the only way you get access to APIs. I am assuming you might have already responded survey email from Linkedin in which you have given all details.

https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program